# C++ Constructor Parameters: string, int, int, int

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am trying to declare a four parameter constructor with a string and three int.  I cannot use *using namespace std* anywhere in my code per my assignment guidelines.

The constructor in the implementation file is:

```
Player (std::string w, int x, int y, int z)
{
}
```

I have a header file for the class specification, a class function implementation file, and a main method file.
I used #include  in both the main method file and the implementation file in a trial and error effort but the IDE keeps saying that a ')' is expected or a semicolon.  But the semicolon would not work because this is the definition of the constructor.  I am stumped.

Comment: You define the c'tor outside the class definition? It should be `Player::Player (...)` then. I can't tell you if that's what you did wrong however, since I can't see your code.

Comment: Oh, and *"I cannot use using namespace std anywhere in my code per my assignment guidelines"* - Good!

Comment: This is not a class method, this is  a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### main.cc

```
#include "player.h"

int main() {
    Player x("player_x", 1, 2, 3);
}
```

#### player.h

```
#ifndef YOUR_PROJECT_PLAYER_H
#define YOUR_PROJECT_PLAYER_H
#include <string>

class Player {
 public:
  Player(std::string w, int x, int y, int z);
};

#endif
```

#### player.cc

```
#include "player.h"

Player::Player(std::string w, int x, int y, int z) {}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insights!  I had typed the #include <string> in the wrong file.  It is now working.

Answer (score 1):

Not using "`using namespace std;`" : Good, use "`using std::string;`" instead. And only in the source files, not header files, I highly recommend.

If the definition is outside of the class declaration, you have to write the class name before the constructor (and member function) names:

```
Player::Player( std::string w, ...)
{
}

void Player::func( ...)
{
}
```